# Pulling ACF options from one page to all

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this wordpress site: www.sensibill.chemicalcode.com and there is a black bar with two buttons on it just below the slider. At the moment it is a Advanced Custom Fields builder block that I created which gives them the options to change the backgrounds colour, button colour, button text, button icons etc

The problem is they want this on all pages but at the moment they will have to add it on each page which is tedious. Is there a way for me to specify that if it is filled out on the homepage display it on all pages?

[this is my builder block php for the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdjoA.png)

[this adds it to the homepage as an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EijAZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ACF pro do the following:

1.) Go to advanced custom fields -> Add New -> Give it a name and add your fields -> Set "Show this field group if" to options is equal to options.

2.) In your button-block.php file set your $buttons variable to the following:

```
$buttons = get_field('button', 'option');
```

If you can't see any output in your loop var_dump the $buttons variable and make sure it's pulling the data in.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced custom fields have a plugin called Options Page:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

This allows you to set up pages globally through the site and to retrieve a field you simply put:

```
<?php 
  $field = get_field('fieldName', 'option');
?>
```

Please bare in mind this is a pro addon which can be purchased at the advanced custom fields website. If you don't want to pay for this, there's alternative ways to do it in Wordpress without the extension.

Comment: I've got the pro version and I've changed my button-block.php to this:

$buttons = get_sub_field('button',5);

But what do I do with this after I get the homepage details?

Note: the 5 is the post ID of my homepage